# How to allow only power button to turn on PC?

Tags: windows

When I shutdown or hibernate my PC it can be easily turned on again by mouse movement, keyboard key pressed, network reconnection, Windows update and God knows what else could do it.

Solutions I know:

- Device manager -> select each device -> properties -> power management -> tick off "allow this device to wake up the computer"
- Switch power supply off

Is there an option somewhere that makes the computer turn off "for real"?

Comment: Disabling hybrid shutdown is one. However that will increase your boot times. Sounds like you’re machine is going into modern standby and not actually turning off.

Comment: Yes.  Your machine is for sure not shutting down. Mouse movement will not start up a computer from true shut down.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your power options so your pc is shutting down "for real".

On Windows 11:

- Press Win key and search for Power Options
- Select **Change what the power buttons do**
- Select **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
- In the Shutdown settings, select **Shut down**
- **Save changes**

See this guide as a reference if you are on a different version of windows.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/shut-down-sleep-or-hibernate-your-pc-2941d165-7d0a-a5e8-c5ad-8c972e8e6eff#ID0EBD=Windows_11